# Orchard CMS (Asp.Net MVC) integration like additional area

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Is possible to integrate orchard to existing Asp.Net MVC3 site like separate area?

Like this:

Web.proj

- View
- Controllers
- Models
- BackendArea
- OrchardCMS files

As a result Orchard CMS will be using for storing resources (strings, images ets.) of main site and easy to manage resources.

Problems:

- I don't whant to use virtual folders
  on IIS.
- Orchard CMS used own Global.asax,
  web.config, earlier version of
  NHibernate and different
  IOC(Spring.net is used for main site)

Comment: Can't find solution to combine existing site and Orchard CMS.

Comment: Possible(implemented) solution: Virtual directory and custom webservice for Orchard CMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the architecture of ASP.NET, not really or at least not cleanly. From what it sounds like, you are really just trying to use the HTTP interface of orchard in a sub-uri, which is possible by setting up a reverse proxy and forwarding requests to a different app living on a different site. [See carlosag's article for a basic overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx). Here are some protips:

- make sure you ignore the route you are going to reverse proxy -- you don't want ASP.NET mvc kicking in and trying to route it.
- Use a virtual directory on the main site where you are reverse proxying. This is where you setup the url rewrites and such.
- Setup the orchard "site" running in a virtual directory under your fake site with the same name as your virtual directory -- helps fool IIS into building URLs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around will be a lot more likely to succeed. What you describe was a non-goal for Orchard.